# Installing Google apps; "Google Services Framework has stopped" after installation

Tags: google-play-store, samsung

The following are the steps I took to get Google apps (Playstore mainly) on my Galaxy Mega 5.8

1. Root
2. Downloaded APKs for: Google Services Framework, Google Login Service, Google Play.
3. Using Root Explorer, I moved all three APKs to the system/app folder.
4. I changed the file permissions to match other items in the folder.
5. Reboot. (Saw "Optimizing apps 3/3")
6. Opened the Play Store and was prompted to log in.

During the process of logging in, a message, "Unfortunately, Google Services Framework has stopped". This message appears periodically, until eventually "Unfortunately, Google Play Store has stopped". When I try to open it again, I get a server error.

This phone did not come with any Google apps including the Play Store.

Can anyone tell me what I might have done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Update: I'm not using any custom ROMs. I'd appreciate instructions on how to flash G-apps as well! My current software version is 4.2.2

I can't seem to boot into Recovery mode. Pressing the Power Button + Volume Up + Home Button simply boots up the device normally.

Comment: Are you using a custom ROM? Why didn't you flash GAPPS then?

Comment: No, I'm not using a custom ROM. I'm using the original Samsung firmware. Can you provide instructions on how to flash G-apps? Thank you!