# E:failed to verify whole-file signature

Tags: rom-flashing, google-apps

I have the original Samsung firmware on my Galaxy Mega 5.8

It doesn't have any of the Google Apps on it, so I decided to flash the G-apps. I got into recovery mode, and selected the appropriate G-apps ZIP, `gapps-jb-20130813-signed.zip`

However, I keep getting the "E:failed to verify whole-file signature" error. I've tried downloading zips from different sources, including the CyanogenMod Wiki Downloads page, the problem seems to persist.

**More**

Here's a list of the steps I took: (My phone is rooted)

1. Download the G-apps zip file.
2. Put it on the root folder of the SD card.
3. Reboot into recovery mode.
4. "Install update from external memory", selected the g-apps zip file.
5. Got the error.

I would really appreciate any help that I can get.

I've also tried downloading the google services framework, play store and google login service APKs separately. However, the play store simply opens and closes. ([Installing Google apps; "Google Services Framework has stopped" after installation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111862/installing-google-apps-google-services-framework-has-stopped-after-installati) )

Comment: Are you using Stock Recovery? If not, then which custom one is it? Philz Touch and TWRP has option to disable signature verification, do it if you have them.

Answer (score 1):

This may help some folks: In my case the error was caused by a corrupt copy of the data file to the USB drive. On the offchance that I had yanked the USB out too early, I recopied, and after that the "whole-file signature" was OK and allowed the firmware update to complete.